# Question regarding Mercurial 1.8.2

Tags: mercurial, httpresponse

i have a big problem with Mercurial 1.8.2 on Mac OSX 10.6
I used for long time with a lot of projects. Now i haven't used for about 4 weeks. Today i tried and OSX crashed with "hg add" command.

So i googled a little bit and found out, that there was a bug in OSX 10.5 where i have to deactive the SET LOCAL in Terminal Preferences.

I've done so - now
 
hg add
hg commit -m "message"

works, but when i run
hg push

i get the following error message where i find no information about

```
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
**  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.8.2+20110401)
** Extensions loaded: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/hg", line 38, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 16, in run
    sys.exit(dispatch(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 36, in dispatch
    return _runcatch(u, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 58, in _runcatch
    return _dispatch(ui, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 601, in _dispatch
    cmdpats, cmdoptions)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 406, in runcommand
    ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 655, in _runcommand
    return checkargs()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 609, in checkargs
    return cmdfunc()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 598, in <lambda>
    d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 433, in check
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 3002, in push
    ui.status(_('pushing to %s\n') % url.hidepassword(dest))
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 75, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 47, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/url.py", line 354, in <module>
    class httpconnection(keepalive.HTTPConnection):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 75, in __getattribute__
    self._load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 47, in _load
    mod = _origimport(head, globals, locals)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/keepalive.py", line 361, in <module>
    class HTTPResponse(httplib.HTTPResponse):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 76, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(self._module, attr)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPResponse'
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: Did you had previously an older version on mercurial installed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do exactly as said in the error message :

> ** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
>   **  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker